# Nim game prolog code

Tags: prolog

I have found a framework for [nim game prolog](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.cs.aau.dk%2F~marius%2Fstudy%2Fnim.pdf&ei=ei2dVMDnGsiqUen7gMAH&usg=AFQjCNFgn8yRda3jbi8hv9ss8OE40QVaOA&sig2=xrn-KhH5nPKG8F1dCyb8nA) code that is given in the art of prolog book. However when i run the code in its original format given in the book in swi prolog editor, i get a lot of errors.And i am not sure whether the code itself is incomplete or logically disordered. Would be greatful if anyone has a solution to it. 
Thanks.

Comment: For a proper question, you need to show the code you tried that is giving you an error and indicate the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the PDF code in a source file, the only problem should be replacing the back quoting to a single quote (about 1 minute overall). Then I get this dialog working:

```
1 ?- goal.
Enter number of matches in heaps [N1, N2, N3]: [5,7,9].
I take 7 matches from 3th heap.
You have heaps of matches: [5,7,2]
Choose heap number from 1 to 3: 2.
Choose number of matches to take from 1 to 7: 2.
So now the heaps are: [5,5,2]
I take 2 matches from 3th heap.
You have heaps of matches: [5,5,0]
Choose heap number from 1 to 3: 3.
Illegal move! Try again.
You have heaps of matches: [5,5,0]
Choose heap number from 1 to 3: 2.
Choose number of matches to take from 1 to 5: 2.
So now the heaps are: [5,3,0]
I take 2 matches from 1th heap.
You have heaps of matches: [3,3,0]
Choose heap number from 1 to 3: 1.
Choose number of matches to take from 1 to 3: 3.
So now the heaps are: [0,3,0]
I take 3 matches from 2th heap.
I won! :)
true 
.
```

Comment: you have it in the PDF. Just copy/paste and do the minimal editing required

Comment: note: I posted this answer just to highlight that the code kindly made available in the PDF is working...